# Can't use string as a HASH ref while "strict refs" when updating hash key in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to update the hash returned by a sub with:

```
sub foo {
    my ($self, $arg) = @_;
    my $results = $self->SUPER::foo($arg);
    $results->{uri} .= 'hey'; # I want to append 'hey' to the value of the already defined 'uri'
    return $results;
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
Can't use string ("hey") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"
```

I know that's a common error, but I can't understand why it happens in my case.

Comment: The value for the uri may be an overloaded object, not just a string?  What is `ref $results->{uri}`?

Comment: Please show the code of `SUPER::foo`.

Comment: `my $self = shift;` is missing from your example code.  Putting that aside, you should be asking your code "What does `$self->SUPER::foo();` return?", and then next "What does the caller of sub `foo` do with the value returned from `$results`?"

Comment: Thanks for the update demonstrating unpacking of `@_` in your example code. Next question: Should `$self->SUPER::foo($self)` really be `$self->SUPER::foo($arg)`?

Comment: Alright, after the edits it's coming together more, but what is posted does not demonstrate what is returned by `$self->SUPER::foo($arg)`, and doesn't show the code that is attempting to use the value returned from `$result` as a hashref.

Comment: Again, please show the code of `SUPER::foo`.

Comment: I know, but when I try to do `print ref($results)` nothing is printed!

Comment: @Borodin the reason why I didn't post it until now is because the code is not mine and I'm not sure to understand it, and so to extrapolate the minimum amount of code.

Comment: Do the file and line number of the error message correspond to a line in `sub foo`?

Comment: The error corresponds to the line of `$results->{uri} .= 'hey'; `

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this from Perl if the contents of `$results` after calling `$self->SUPER::foo($arg);` is the string literal `'hey'` instead of a HASHREF - much as if you were to do the following:

```
my $results = 'hey'
$results->{uri} .= 'hey';
```

Comment: Are you saying that `$results` is actually a string?

Comment: Yes, specifically the string "hey" and that's why calling `ref` on it returns an empty string.